# How can I get all rows with existing value of column in array

Tags: php, sql

I have table **A** and an `array`.

**A**

```
+----+-------+-------+--------+
| id | data1 | data2 | number |
+----+-------+-------+--------+
| 1  | xxx   | mmm   | 2      |
+----+-------+-------+--------+
| 2  | abc   | hij   | 4      |
+----+-------+-------+--------+
| 3  | qwe   | lol   | 3      |
+----+-------+-------+--------+
| 4  | asd   | pip   | 2      |
+----+-------+-------+--------+
| 5  | zui   | aaa   | 4      |
+----+-------+-------+--------+
| 6  | yxc   | ert   | 4      |
+----+-------+-------+--------+
| 7  | lop   | flo   | 3      |
+----+-------+-------+--------+
| 8  | foo   | zzz   | 1      |
+----+-------+-------+--------+
```

`array`

```
$arr = array("0", "1", "2", "3");
```

Now I want to get all `data` from **A** where `number` exists in `$arr`.

So the result should be:

```
id data1 data2
1  xxx   mmm   
3  qwe   lol
4  asd   pip
7  lop   flo
8  foo   zzz
```

Rows like:

```
id data1 data2
2  abc   hij
5  zui   aaa
```

Are not in the result, because their `number` is 4 and not in `$arr`.

Comment: What is your current SQL query and what seems to go wrong?